# Validating xml against xsd schema - no matching global declaration

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I'm running into trouble while validating my XML file. Error message is "Element '{some_namespace}contact': No matching global declaration available for the validation root."

I do realize there must be something wrong with namespaces but after hours of fighting I cannot make it work (validate).

I hope you can help me with this; maybe there's a stupid thing I'm missing all the time (I'm quite new to XML/XSD topic).

**My XML**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <abc:contact xmlns:abc="some_namespace">
     <session>d22737b4aad7b641eea7c85e7294426b84b73713</session>
     <id>23372455488</id>
   </abc:contact>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:targetNamespace="some_namespace">
  <xsd:element name="contact">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="session" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer"/>
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

To validate I use xmllint (console), NPP+XML Tools and PHP (DOMDocument::schemaValidate) - all with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema document, replace

```
xmlns:targetNamespace="some_namespace"
```

with

```
targetNamespace="some_namespace"
```

(The target namespace of the schema document is identified using the `targetNamespace` attribute on the `schema` element, not by binding a magic namespace prefix to the target namespace.)

Comment: This did not help in my case. I have the targetNamespace allright in the XSD Schema, but still getting this error. I cannot find the mistake in the XML. I will create my own question...